# Why is my serial.write sending data twice

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am trying to emulate a microncontroller sending data through a serial port by creating an app that sends bytes continuously to another app for GUI purposes with the receiving routine.

I am using this method to send my bytes from the sender instance:

```
Write(vout, 0, 13);
```

Where Write is defined as:

```
public void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    // preconditions checks are omitted
    serialPort1.Write(buffer, offset, count);
}
```

*vout* is an array of bytes I manually populate from data simulating sensors in real time.

When receiving data in the GUI application, I am using this:

```
private void comport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
      if (!comport.IsOpen) return;
      int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
      //For loop for getting all values in buffer to 0
      comport.Read(buffer, 0, 13);
      Update_counter();//Updates counter by 1.
}
```

The **second time/any time afterwards** I send something, it is sent twice, or at least that is what my counter variable is implying.

I am not sure if this has something to do with the actual serial buffer, or if I am using the write and read methods incorrectly.

Also, I am setting the COMPORT to 9600 baudrate, 8 bits, stopbit 1, parity NONE.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "It is sent twice": If you send: "ABC", do you get "AABBCC", or do you get "ABCABC". Do you get this in one event, or do you get this in several events?

Comment: Sorry, it is not duplicated. more than sending it twice, it is triggering the datareceived() event, twice, but the data is not duplicated. Last time I got the error, I had something like (Assuming I sent ABCD), after the first iteration which is flawless, for any sent routine afterwards, the first package would read A000, and the second package BCD0..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is, that you are reading more bytes than there are available right now:

```
int nrOfAvailableBytes = comport.BytesToRead;
comport.Read(buffer, 0, 13);
```

So even if the comport tells you that there is only one byte available, you decide to read 13 bytes.

[SerialPort.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) tells you:

> Fewer bytes are read if count is greater than the number of bytes in the input buffer.

Solution: only read the bytes that are available right now.

Comment: You might be right, I had the idea that by asking specifically for 13 bytes each time I read something would not be as robust. I will take this into consideration, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ignore the value returned by `Read()`, it returns the number of bytes that were put in your buffer. So if you want to read 13 bytes and it returns fewer than that, keep track of the count and read until you hit the desired amount of bytes.

In other words, you're going to have to implement your `//For loop` comment:

```
int totalBytesRead = 0;
int bytesToRead = 13;
do
{
    totalBytesRead += comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead - totalBytesRead);
} 
while (totalBytesRead < bytesToRead);
```

Comment: This code prevents the receivedData() event to be triggered twice, but instead I only read a shifted-one-tothe-left buffer. If I send ABCD at the beginning, now I am only reading BCDD (where I am assuming the last D was just not updated at all).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a consistent result by combining both answers. I feel like is sort of redundant but this has been the most promising one.

```
        int n_available_bytes = comport.BytesToRead;

        //Reset buffer array
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = 0;
        }
        
        //Read, update charts, save to CSV only when the buffer has all the bytes
        if (n_available_bytes == bytesToRead)
        {
            do
            {
            totalBytesRead += comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead - totalBytesRead);
            }
            while (totalBytesRead < bytesToRead);

            if (totalBytesRead == bytesToRead)
            {
                totalBytesRead = 0;
            }

            HandleSerialData(buffer);

            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Fill_chart));
      
       }
```